# dynamic row deletion is not taking place after deletion of the delected row

Tags: javascript, jquery

Data is coming from the backend and every row has a delete button which deletes the row data from the db.

The data is successfully deleting but the row is not deleted.

I have tried with various question over here and tried with every possible sollution but didn't worked for me

```
function myFunction(id){
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/CurdAppBackend/emp/delete/"+ id;

    $.ajax({
        type : "DELETE",
        url : url,
        success: function (result) {       
               alert("DELETED");
               f$('.table tbody').closest(id).remove();
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(e));
        }
    });
};
```

### This is how the table data are loading

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/CurdAppBackend/emp/allEmp";

    $.get({
        url: url,
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(data){
            var users = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

            for (var i in users) {
                $("tbody").
                append("<tr id="+users[i].empId+"> \
                            <td>" +  users[i].empId + "</td> \
                            <td>" +  users[i].createdAt + "</td> \
                            <td>" +  users[i].empName + "</td> \
                            <td>" + users[i].empMobile + "</td> \
                            <td>" + users[i].empDesg + "</td> \
                            <td>" + users[i].unit + "</td> \
                            <td>" +'<button onclick="myFunction('+users[i].empId+')" class="btn btn-outline-danger" id=del>DELETE</button>'+"</td> \
                            </tr>");              
            }                   


        },
        error: function(e){
            alert("Something Went Wrong  "+e);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your `function2` is creating an event binding.  It's not deleting anything

Comment: this i have tried earlier but it also not working check the edited answer

Comment: What is `id`?  And `closest()` goes up through ancestors, not down through children

Comment: i have tried this also ````$('#id").remove()```` this is also not working

Comment: ````id```` i.e i have provided to each row i.e the emp id

Comment: But what is an example value?  Because an id selector has to start with `#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use: `$('#'+id).remove();`

instead of: `f$('.table tbody').closest(id).remove();`

Answer (score 0):

There many method to do that:

2 methods given below:

**1 st method:**

```
function myFunction(id, obj){
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/CurdAppBackend/emp/delete/"+ id;

    $.ajax({
        type : "DELETE",
        url : url,
        success: function (result) {       
               $(obj).parents('tr').remove();
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(e));
        }
    });
};
```

Change you code To: Because in templeting method is best, Because you will not forget any quot and easy to implement, and all

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/CurdAppBackend/emp/allEmp";

    $.get({
        url: url,
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(data){
            var users = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

            for (var i in users) {
                $("tbody").
                append(`<tr id="${users[i].empId}">
                            <td>${users[i].empId}</td>
                            <td>${users[i].createdAt}</td>
                            <td>${users[i].empName}</td>
                            <td>${users[i].empMobile}</td>
                            <td>${users[i].empDesg}</td>
                            <td>${users[i].unit}</td>
                            <td><button onclick="myFunction(${users[i].empId}, this)" class="btn btn-outline-danger" id=del>DELETE</button></td>
                            </tr>`);              
            }                   


        },
        error: function(e){
            alert("Something Went Wrong  "+e);
        }
    });
```

here I am passing refrence with function calling, as this and getting in obj, then find there parent 'tr', then remove them.

**2nd Method**
change give line:

```
f$('.table tbody').closest(id).remove();
```

to

```
$('table').find(`id="${id}"`).remove();
```

I am find it, because in some case of dynamic loading data though ajax, not found.
Then we have to find that object in dom,